# how to add dynamic value as object field name in java?

Tags: java, json, class, getter-setter

** Query**

```
@PostMapping("/students/create")
    public Student  postCandidate(@RequestBody Student  student) {

        Student  _student = repository.save(new Student  (student.getStudentname(), student.setRollno()));
        return _student;
    }
```

**Code:**

```
public class Student  {
    private String studentname;
    private int rollno;
    public Student(int rollno, String studentname) {
         this.rollno = rollno;
         this.studentname = studentname;
    }

    public String getStudentname() {
         return studentname;
    }
    public void setStudentname(String studentname) {
    this.studentname = studentname;
    }
    public int getRollno() {
    return rollno;
    }
    public void setRollno(int rollno) {
    this.rollno = rollno;
    }
}
```

Instead of getting rollno ="123" I want to get the dynamic data which I have passed: "ram"="123'

example:

```
{studentname:john, john:"123"},
{studentname:Ram, Ram:"124"}
```

Comment: to get the `rollno` that you passed in, use the `getRollno()` method you defined: `int rollno = new Student(3, "").getRollno()`

Comment: It's quite unclear what the bigger picture is here. Please provide more information. If you're really accepting JSON (which your example *nearly* is, but it's not quite valid JSON) you'd probably be best using a JSON library to manage the data, at least in the early stages of handling it.

Comment: Please update your question with a valid JSON and your attempt at solving the problem

Comment: for example : {"name": "krishna","age": "22"} this is my json, i want to save  it like  {"name": "krishna","age": "22","krishna":true}. here value is stored as a field name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any JSON library to read the json data.

1) Read the value key `studentname` to get student name.
2) Read the value of key `student's name from #1`

Also, json provided in question is not valid. I have assumed the correct json would be

```
[
  {
    studentname: "john",
    john: "123"
  },
  {
    studentname: "Ram",
    Ram: "124"
  }
]
```

My attempt using GSON library:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class GsonTest {

    private static String json = "JSON STRING HERE";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        JsonElement jsonElement = gson.fromJson(json, JsonElement.class);
        JsonArray array = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();
        Iterator<JsonElement> iterator = array.iterator();

        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            JsonObject item = iterator.next().getAsJsonObject();
            // Roll No is read by reading dynamic key which is student name
            Student student = new Student(item.get(item.get("studentname").getAsString()).getAsInt(), item.get("studentname").getAsString());
            students.add(student);
        }
        students.forEach(item -> {
            System.out.println("Name : " + item.getStudentname() + " Roll No : " + item.getRollno());
        });
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Name : john Roll No : 123
Name : Ram Roll No : 124
```